# How to pass reference parameters as PHP in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

my question is as simple as this: How can I pass parameters as reference or as value in JavaScript as I could do in PHP.

Example with PHP:

```
    function increase(&$value){ 
        $value++;
        return $value; 
    }
    $number = 4;
    echo increase($number) . "<br/>";
    echo $number;
```

How can I accomplish something similar with JavaScript?

Thank you and Blessings.

Comment: See https://www.codekoel.com/pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-java-script

TLDR; Values cannot be passed-by-reference. Objects are always passed by reference

Comment: @rickdenhaan, that's a better duplicate link than mine IMO

Comment: Thank you @reed your comment has answered  my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the return value to a variable.

```
const nextNumber = increase(number);
console.log(nextNumber);
```

where `increase` does the same thing as your PHP function:

```
function increase($value){ 
    $value++;
    return $value; 
}
```

Comment: It's the same as in @ReynaldRamirez's code. Increment a variable and return it.

Comment: Your code doesn't work the same as in PHP. If you will run `increase` multiple times in JS it will always return the same value, but in PHP it will increase value every time. So in JS if you will pass 4 it will return always 5, but in PHP it will return 5, 6, 7, etc.